# Make up for keyboard layout differences between macOS and Windows when using RDP

Tags: macos, windows-10, keyboard, remote-desktop, keyboard-layout

I'm using Microsoft's official Remote Desktop client for macOS to connect to a machine that runs Windows 10. On both my Mac and this Windows machine, I use a physically American QWERTY keyboard with the Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard layout.

On Windows, the physical key <kbd>`~</kbd> maps to a <kbd>/</kbd>. <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does a <kbd>\</kbd>, and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does a <kbd>|</kbd>. This is a very important key for a developer, especially on Windows.

On macOS, this key maps to <kbd>ù</kbd>. You do a forward slash with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>é</kbd>, a backslash with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ù</kbd> and a pipe with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

My problem is that when connecting to the Windows machine, Windows recognizes the <kbd>`~</kbd> key as a <kbd>ù</kbd> key instead of a <kbd>/</kbd>, but none of the key combinations that I use on macOS to produce slashes and pipes work. There seems to be no way, using this keyboard layout, to produce these characters from my Mac's keyboard.

Is there a way that I can make the keyboard work like it does on either macOS or Windows but not a strange hybrid of the two?

Comment: [not an answer] There are *some* fixes in the new RDC beta - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/ - though unfortunately not for those mappings :/

Comment: @Tetsujin, it actually *does* solve the problem: using that beta, my ù key becomes a / key as it would normally be on Windows. If you post the same thing as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Oh, cool - glad it helped. Will drop in a quick answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some nice fixes in the new [RDC Mac beta](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/) - though not for all mappings, some of the remaps they have set up are really quite useful.

[Personal opinion, I find it considerably better than the current release for many reasons.]